# Unable to deploy on Heroku after migrating rails app from 3.2.3 to rails 4.0.0.rc2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have recently migrated an existing rails 3.2.3 app to rails 4.0.0.rc2. I have made all the necessary changes and have been able to make it work fine on my local. But when I push this to heroku - "git push heroku master", it says failed to push some refs. The follwoing is the stack trace -

-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in`new'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in`initialize'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in`postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in`checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in`block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in`block in connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in`retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in`connection'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:203:in `table_exists?'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/lib/custom_active_record/domain_constants_pool.rb:13:in`evaluate_constants'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/app/models/user_type.rb:4:in `<class:UserType>'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/app/models/user_type.rb:1:in`'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`block in require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in`load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in`load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/app/models/user.rb:13:in`'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in`load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in`require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in`const_missing'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in`block in constantize'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in`inject'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:534:in`get'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:565:in `constantize'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise.rb:274:in`get'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in`modules'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in`default_used_route'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise.rb:308:in`new'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise.rb:308:in `add_mapping'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in`block in devise_for'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in`devise_for'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/config/routes.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in`instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in`draw'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in`load'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in`load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`block in load_paths'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`load_paths'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in`block in updater'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in`execute'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in`execute_if_updated'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in`initialize!'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`block in require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`require'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in`block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_uqaojzpp3n68/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

I use postgres on my local also, and its working fine. This app was previously deployed on heroku. I have added ruby 2.0.0 in Gemfile and the logs indicate that they are using ruby 2.0.0. I am not sure how to debug this. Is there any other change required to migrate existing app on heroku to 4.0.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is during slug compilation the environment variables are not available to your app. Try installing the [user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) labs feature.

Comment: Thanks Sunny. I enabled labs and the app is up now.